# Completeness of red-black tree operations

Tags: algorithm-analysis, trees, binary-search-trees, red-black-trees

Red-black trees are defined to have the following invariants:

- The nodes are in sorted order (it is a binary search tree).
- The root is black, and leaves are black.
- Every red node has black children.
- Every path to the root passes through the same number of black nodes.

There is also an obvious "empty" operation (just a leaf) and a more involved "insert" operation described on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Insertion), as well as an [erase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Removal) operation, and with some effort one can show that these operations preserve the red-black invariants just described.

My question is about the converse. Is it the case that:

1. Every tree satisfying the red-black invariants is reachable by applying `insert` to `empty` with an appropriately chosen order of operations.
2. Every tree satisfying the red-black invariants is reachable by applying `insert` or `erase` to `empty` with an appropriately chosen order of operations.

My guess is that the answer to 1 is "no" and the answer to 2 is "yes", but I have no proof of either case.

Comment: Have you consider the problem with respect to 2-3-4 trees? Maybe it would be easier to use those trees.